# Create index locks MySQL 5.6 table. How to avoid that?

Tags: mysql

I need to create an index on a large InnoDB production table and want to do this without locking the table in any way. I am using MySQL 5.6 (.38-83.90).

I tried

```
create index my_index on my_table(col1, col2);
```

Neither columns are primary keys. col1 is a foreign key.

Well, this totally locked the table. Other queries were stalled with **"Waiting for table metadata lock"** bringing my website to its knees. I had to kill the *create index* query.

From this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html I thought that it would not lock the table: "... no syntax changes are required... The table remains available for read and write operations while the index is being created or dropped."

I see that I can set LOCK=NONE or LOCK=SHARED, but I don't see that it should be necessary or, if it is, which one I need to use.

"You can specify LOCK=NONE to assert that concurrent DML is permitted during the DDL operation. *MySQL automatically permits concurrent DML when possible.*"

"You can specify LOCK=SHARED to assert that concurrent queries are permitted during a DDL operation. *MySQL automatically permits concurrent queries when possible.*"

None of the limitations https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-limitations.html seem to apply to my case.

What am I missing?

Comment: For those voting to close, how is asking how to create a MySQL index not within the programming scope? There are tons of MySQL questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Well technically this is a DBA question https://dba.stackexchange.com/ - not a 'programming' question as such (its not how to 'write' a SQL query in code for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess (just a guess) is that you are missing the `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` clause on the `CREATE INDEX` statement.

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table(col1, col2) ALGORITHM=INPLACE ;
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Also be aware of transactions acquiring and holding metadata locks.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/metadata-locking.html

Any transaction that has referenced `my_table` will continue to hold a metadata lock on that table until the transaction is committed or rolled back. I suggest checking the `TRANSACTIONS` section of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` output.